# Reset values of a column based on conditions from another column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with columns 'Time' and 'Col1'. I would like to write a simple function that changes the values of 'Col1' between the time intervals from 'Time' column.

I don't know why the following code produces the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
val = 5
time1 = 200
time2 = 300
def reset_value(df, val, time1, time2):
   df.loc[df['Time'] >= time1 and df['Time']<time2, 'Col1'] = val
   return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND` and add parentheses:

```
df.loc[(df['Time'] >= time1) & (df['Time']<time2), 'Col1'] = val
```

Or use [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```
df.loc[df['Time'].ge(time1) & df['Time'].lt(time2), 'Col1'] = val
```